# Hymns that talk to God

Tags: prayer, hymns

I am looking for hymns that talk to God / Jesus / Holy Spirit instead of about Him or us. Prayer like hymns if it makes sense.

English is not my primary language so I know only one: "Fairest Lord Jesus"

Ant help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: There are lots of these. Have you gone through a hymn book looking for them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This hymn is addressed to all three persons within the One Being of God. It was composed by Anglican bishop Reginald Heber (early 19th century) and is an all-time favourite in Hymns Ancient and Modern.  Here are the lyrics:

> Holy, Holy, Holy! Lord God Almighty!
> Early in the morning our song shall rise to Thee;
> Holy, Holy, Holy! Merciful and Mighty!
> God in Three Persons, blessed Trinity!

> Holy, Holy, Holy! All the saints adore Thee,
> Casting down their golden crowns around the glassy sea;
> Cherubim and seraphim falling down before Thee,
> Which wert, and art, and evermore shalt be.

> Holy, Holy, Holy! though the darkness hide Thee,
> Though the eye of sinful man, thy glory may not see:
> Only Thou art holy, there is none beside Thee,
> Perfect in power in love, and purity.

> Holy, holy, holy! Lord God Almighty!
> All thy works shall praise thy name in earth, and sky, and sea;
> Holy, Holy, Holy! merciful and mighty,
> God in Three Persons, blessed Trinity!

Intended for use on Trinity Sunday, the text invites worshipers to join in praising the trinitarian deity, paraphrasing Revelation 4:1–11.

Source: [Holy, Holy, Holy! Lord God Almighty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holy,_Holy,_Holy!_Lord_God_Almighty#Text)